# concatenate data based on a certain sequence

Tags: r, loops, concatenation, rbind

my data look like this way, and variable day ranges from 1 to 232. This is just a shorter version of the data, the real data have over 20000000 rows with variable 'day' ranging from 1 to 232

```
day time
1   2
1   2
2   2
2   3
3   4
3   5
4   4
4   2
```

and I have a vector that contains 1000 of randomly selected from sequences of variable day (1-232), say

```
df=c(3,4,1,2,...,4,1,3)
```

I want to create a new dataset that sorts based on the sequence. The we first extract day=3 from the data, and then extract day=4 after it, then extracr day=1 and rbind thereafter. For example, the first 4 sequence should look like this way:

```
day time
3   4
3   5
4   4
4   2
1   2
1   2
2   2
2   3
```

Comment: What's the sorting logic?

Comment: based on sequence df that ranges 1-232 of values in variable day. for example, the first number in df is 3, so we extract all rows that day=3, then rbind all rows where day=4 after day=3, and then rbind all rows that day=1 after it.

Comment: The logic wont work out. you are sorting as the sequence. ie in the sequence, you have `3` being first, yet you take all the `day==3` and put them as first. Then you have `4` as the second, then you take all `day==4` as second and so forth. What is the purpose of `4,1,3` at the end of the sequence? How will they be used?

Comment: the sequence 'df' is 1000 random numbers selected from the value of variable 'day'

Comment: I still don't get it, why should 3 come first?

Comment: 'df' is just a randomly selected number ranging from 1-232, so it can be any number from 1-232, it can repeat for any sequence. So we just need to extract certain rows based on variable 'day' and rbind thereafter.

Comment: the sequence should only have unique values, there should be no repetition if at all you are using it in ordering. eg if you have a sequence like `c(4,3,4,1)` should 4 come before 3 or after 3??

Comment: @r2evans, I would close my question when resolved

Comment: Sure. Do the two answers here not resolve it? (For instance, the use of `data.table::fread` is just to get data into the answer -- make it reproducible -- I think it is assumed that you would already have a frame from however you read in your data.)

Comment: @r2evans I read my data as a dataframe, but I still got error Error: `[.data.frame`(df, seq, on = "day") : 
  unused argument (on = "day")

Comment: That's because you are trying to do a `data.table` operation on a `data.frame`. If your variable is named `x`, try `setDT(x)` before attempting @Chase's answer (and you might want to read up on the advantages of `data.table`, but they only work if you use them correctly). Or just try my answer as-is. I'd think they would both work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base R method:

```r
x <- structure(list(day = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), time = c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
df <- c(3,4,1,2,4,1,3)
do.call("rbind.data.frame", lapply(df, function(i) subset(x, day == i)))
#    day time
# 5    3    4
# 6    3    5
# 7    4    4
# 8    4    2
# 1    1    2
# 2    1    2
# 3    2    2
# 4    2    3
# 71   4    4
# 81   4    2
# 11   1    2
# 21   1    2
# 51   3    4
# 61   3    5
```

The use of `do.call("rbind.data.frame", ...)` is prone to typical `data.frame` instantiation, meaning if your real data has any columns of type `character`, you will likely want to do

```r
do.call("rbind.data.frame", c(lapply(df, function(i) subset(x, day == i)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
```

Also, it could easily be replaced (without the risk of `factor`s) with `data.table::rbindlist` or `dplyr::bind_rows`.

Comment: hi thanks for your answer! What if my real data have over 20000000 rows with variable 'day' ranging from 1 to 232 and could not be typed in using the structure function?

Comment: What have you tried? I don't see why this would not work as-is. The only limitation I can think of is if your data exceeds the RAM of your computer (which would block any solution for this question).

Comment: I am now trying your solution and it is still running. I could use supercomputer to run if needed. Will let you know if it works, thanks again!

Comment: 20M rows is a lot to handle, certainly. I can deal with that much data in R without too much trouble, but it pays to be careful. Unfortunately your problem does not stay "efficient" well at all with the calculus of databases, so I suspect you will likely have some unavoidable delay.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you can do this in a pretty straight forward manner with `data.table()`:

```r
library(data.table)
df <- fread(text = "day time
1   2
1   2
2   2
2   3
3   4
3   5
4   4
4   2", header = TRUE)

seqs <- data.table(day = c(3,4,1,2,4,1,3))

df[seqs, on = "day"]
#>     day time
#>  1:   3    4
#>  2:   3    5
#>  3:   4    4
#>  4:   4    2
#>  5:   1    2
#>  6:   1    2
#>  7:   2    2
#>  8:   2    3
#>  9:   4    4
#> 10:   4    2
#> 11:   1    2
#> 12:   1    2
#> 13:   3    4
#> 14:   3    5
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: OP has numbers up to 232. I assume making a "sequence" manually would defeat the purpose of using R.

Comment: @NelsonGon, the sequence is already availabel. This here is just a snippet of what OP wants

Comment: @NelsonGon - I'm not sure I understand how your comment changes the answer above? If the OP already has the full sequence available, I assume they would simply drop that in place of my manually created sequence available...they didn't provide a reproducible example...so I made one.[

Comment: No problem. I guess I just didn't quite get the logic. It appeared to me that there's no set sequence and that this also needed to be manually produced. Ah, I just saw it.

Comment: @NelsonGon - `seqs` above is simply based off the bread crumb of logic in the original question...you can replace `seqs` with any other sequence of numbers that has value / is defined elsewhere...can do `sample(1:232, 1000, replace = TRUE)` for all the code cares.

Comment: thanks for all the answers! actually the data shown above is just a shorter version of first four of the 'day' variable, and the function 'fread' would not work. Is there other ways of deal with the data that contains over 20000000 rows?

Comment: @vera_kkk - you'll have to be more specific about how `fread` did not work. `fread` in the code above just creates your data example as an R object (since you didn't give a reproducible example). If you're having trouble reading your data into R (say from a CSV file), that is a hardware limitation. You can look to read in chunks, only read in column you need, etc. - but that is decidedly a different question than what you have asked here.

Comment: @Chase, I'm inferring there was a little misunderstanding (1) of the purpose for `fread` to bring in sample data, but more important (2) the importance of being a `data.table` *class* object. I like this solution and many DT-based solutions for speed and overall efficiency (I \*really\* like the join-concept of this one), and at the same time I realize less-experienced R users don't often get those nuances. You have my upvote :-)